# Python, Numpy Stack overflow

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, stack-overflow

I'm trying to do some image manipulation in python but I was having some trouble with the stack overflowing. After reading a little, I edited the np.array to take an extra parameter dtype='int64'. (It worked fine before, provided I didn't call the threshold method)

This solves the exception error but when I try to plot the image to plot it, it doesn't work. No exception, it just plots nothing. The error isn't in the threshold method because even when I comment it out and run it, it still doesn't plot. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Full code below:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import math

def threshold(imageArray):
     balanceAr = []
     newArray = imageArray


     for eachRow in imageArray:
         for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/float(len(eachPix[:3]))
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)

     balance = reduce(lambda x , y: x + y , eachPix[:3]/float(len(balanceAr)))

    for eachRow in newArray:
         for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x , y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/float(len(eachPix[:3])) > balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
                eachPix[3] = 255
            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0
                eachPix[3] = 255


y = Image.open('images/numbers/y0.5.png')
yar = np.asarray(y, dtype='int64')

threshold(yar)


fig = plt.figure()
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,3), rowspan=4, colspan=3)

ax3.imshow(yar)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the size of the image? Can you post it?

Comment: Are you sure it was the *stack* that was overflowing? Or did you actually get `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why MatPlotLib won't plot your image, but I *can* tell you about some problems with your `threshold` function.

1. You write `newArray = imageArray` but this just means that `newArray` is another name for the same array. This means that your `threshold` function overwrites the original image, which can be very inconvenient (especially when testing). You might want to take a copy of the image:

   ```
   newArray = imageArray.copy()
   ```
2. In this group of lines:

   ```
   balanceAr = []
   for eachRow in imageArray:
       for eachPix in eachRow:
           avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, eachPix[:3])/float(len(eachPix[:3]))
           balanceAr.append(avgNum)
   ```

   you are computing a (flattened) array `balanceAr` whose entries are the mean values of the first three channels for each pixel. You do so by looping over each pixel in the image. But NumPy is most efficient when you can *vectorize* the code and compute the result for all pixels in one operation. In this case you can use [NumPy's fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) to get the first three channels of the image:

   ```
   colour_channels = imageArray[...,:3]
   ```

   and then call [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to get the average for each pixel:

   ```
   balanceAr = colour_channels.mean(axis=-1)
   ```

   (This constructs a 2-dimensional array: if you *really* wanted a flattened version you could call the [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten) method, but that's not necessary as I will explain below.)
3. In this line:

   ```
   balance = reduce(lambda x , y: x + y , eachPix[:3]/float(len(balanceAr)))
   ```

   It looks as though your intention was to compute the mean value of `balanceAr`, but you messed up and only replaced *one* of the occurrences of `eachPix[:3]` by `balanceAr`. So obviously this computes the wrong result.

   What you need, of course, is:

   ```
   balance = balanceAr.mean()
   ```
4. In the next group of lines you replace pixels in the image that have a higher mean colour channel than `balance` by white, and a lower mean by black. Again, you should vectorize this operation. You can compute a *mask array*, a Boolean array that is `True` for the pixels that are higher than average:

   ```
   mask = balanceAr > balance
   ```

   Construct an empty image of the right size:

   ```
   result = np.empty(imageArray.shape)
   ```

   Set pixels in the mask to white and other pixels to black:

   ```
   result[mask] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
   result[~mask] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
   ```
5. Thinking about this algorithm more carefully, it's clear that you don't actually need to take the average of the colour channels. The division by 3 is always the same, so it can simply be omitted, and we could use the *sum* of the colour channels instead. (Calling [`numpy.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) instead of [`numpy.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).)
6. Putting all that together, here's how I'd program it:

   ```
   import numpy as np

   WHITE = np.array((255, 255, 255, 255), dtype=np.uint8)
   BLACK = np.array((  0,   0,   0, 255), dtype=np.uint8)

   def threshold2(img, high=WHITE, low=BLACK):
       """Return a new image whose pixels are `high` where pixels in `img`
       have a higher sum of colour channels than the average for the
       image, and `low` elsewhere.

       """
       colsum = img[...,:3].sum(axis=-1)
       mask = colsum > colsum.mean()
       result = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
       result[mask] = high
       result[~mask] = low
       return result
   ```

   This is about 200 times faster than your code:

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (400, 400, 4))
   >>> timeit(lambda:threshold2(img), number=1) # mine
   0.05198820028454065
   >>> timeit(lambda:threshold(img), number=1) # yours
   10.539333346299827
   ```
7. The sum of the colour channels of an image is a bit like the [luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_%28relative%29) of an image, except that it doesn't take into account the different physiological responses to the channels (green is perceived as brighter than red which is perceived as brighter than blue). Perhaps you should be using 0.2126 *R* + 0.7152 *G* + 0.0722 *B* instead of *R* + *G* + *B*?

   If that's right, you need something like this:

   ```
   # sRGB luminosity coefficients, plus 0 for the alpha channel
   LUMINOSITY = np.array((0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0))

   def threshold3(img, high=WHITE, low=BLACK, luminosity=LUMINOSITY):
       """Return a new image whose pixels are `high` where pixels in `img`
       have a higher luminance than the average for the image, and `low`
       elsewhere. The optional `luminosity` argument provides the
       multipliers for the red, green and blue channels.

       """
       luminance = (img * luminosity).sum(axis=-1)
       mask = luminance > luminance.mean()
       result = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
       result[mask] = high
       result[~mask] = low
       return result
   ```